# Как организовать систему ведения учета рабочего времени сотрудников?

Tags: excel

Имеется отдел с сотрудниками, которые каждый день заполняют таблицу в excel файле с названием деятельности и количеством потраченного времени на эту деятельность:

```
Название деятельности    | Кол-во часов
Перебор книг             | 5
Заполнение документации  | 0.5
.........................| ...
```

Определенные поля суммируются

Каждый сотрудник заполняет свой файл и в конце месяца/недели отправляет по почте/сетке начальнику отдела.

Требуется: подсчитать, вывести кол-во времени на каждой деятельности по всем сотрудникам отдела сразу, которые заполняют каждый свой файл.

Как лучше всего это сделать посредством excel? Или с помощью php.

Comment: Заведите нормальную систему, по типу Redmine.

Comment: Примите в штат старушку-табельщицу. Она наладит учёт без всяких этих систем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посредством Excel решение может быть следующее:

1. Каждому сотруднику предоставляется для заполнения заранее сформированный шаблон в формате MS Excel (далее - `Шаблон`) желательно с единым формализованным списком `Названий деятельности`, содержащий поля:

`Сотрудник` - Ф.И.О. сотрудника, предоставившего информацию;

`Неделя` - номер отчетной недели;

`Название деятельности` - описание вида деятельности;

`Кол-во часов` - затраченное время.

Например:

[image: Таблица сотрудника по учету деятельности]

2. Заполненные `Шаблоны` направляются для свода (почта/сеть) начальнику отдела;
3. `Шаблоны` с информацией от сотрудников объединяются в `Общую таблицу отдела`. Для автоматизации объединения можно использовать надстройку [`RDBMerge`](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm);

Например, данные по нескольким сотрудникам за две недели:

[image: Общая таблица отдела за две недели]

4. С помощью сводных таблиц на основании данных `Общей таблице отдела` формируем всевозможные срезы.

Например:

[image: Сводная таблица]

`+` решения

- лучший вариант, чем ничего;
- минимальные необходимый набор средств;
- достаточно навыков квалифицированного пользователя Excel;
- гибкость при внесении изменений количества полей `Шаблона` и т.п.;
- автоматический расчет необходимых показателей в динамике по времени.

`-` решения

- проблемы с объединением данных из-за некорректности заполнения `Шаблонов` Сотрудниками;
- большая доля ручных операции для получения `Общей таблицы отдела`;